# Safer way to store record of in-app purchases than NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase, storekit

Once the user has purchased an item in my app, or restored their existing purchases, the record of that is stored in `NSUserDefaults`. I'm probably right in assuming that this file can be easily edited, especially on a jailbroken device, and thus they can claim to have purchased things which they haven't.

I was wondering if there was a safer way to store records of in-app purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user purchases an IAP have the App grab the users identifierForVendor, modify it in some way (e.g. modulo 63, or multiply it by some number, or use it to seed srandom() and generate the next random() ) and write the result to NSUserDefaults.  Then test that NSUserDefaults to see if it has the correct number in it.

Answer (score 2):

Anything stored on a jailbroken phone can be modified. Putting it in the keychain makes it slightly harder to modify, but doesn't offer any real protection on jailbroken devices. I'd store the list on the server, and whenever a user asks for additional content, check that list before sending new content to the client.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to gaining access to keychain info on a jailbroken phone?

Comment: Here you go - https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper. This tool will dump out the entire keychain on a jailbroken iphone. Or really, google search for any of N different ways to access/modify the keychain on JB iPhones.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks. Live and learn. So this is an argument for not storing anything that really needs to be secured on the device. E.g., username/password. Perhaps only store temporary (e.g., time-limited) credentials in the keychain? It's also a tradeoff between annoying the user (by them having to re-enter a username/password from time to time) versus security.